# Can I safely backup my system by simply tarring things?

Tags: macos, backup, tar

Of course, the recommended method of backing up an OSX machine is to use Time Machine. But let's say that, for whatever reason, I'm deadset on doing it myself.

If I simply tar up things I care about (my user directory, /Applications, Application Support, Libraries etc), and later extract them to a fresh OSX install, will everything work? I know I have to use explicit flags to preserve ownership and permissions, but assuming I do that, does `tar` completely preserve all the metadata OSX wants like resource forks and all the rest of it?

Comment: You should be careful about blindly overwriting /Applications, the system libraries, etc because if your fresh install is a newer version than what you backed up, it will very likely lead to trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time Machine would probably be easier and or better then using `tar` as there is no mention in the man page that it will preserve resource forks and HFS meta-data information.  *See Edit below.

`ditto` does and more... From it's man page:

> **ditto** will preserve resource forks and HFS meta-data information when copying unless instructed other- wise using **−−norsrc** .
>   Similarly, **ditto** will preserve extended attributes and Access
>   Control Lists (ACLs) unless **−−noextattr** or **−−noacl** is passed.
>   DITTONORSRC can be set in the environment as an alias to **−−norsrc 
>   −−noextattr −−noacl** on the command line.

**Edit:**  While the `tar` man page did not specifically mention "preserve resource forks and HFS meta-data information" like **ditto** did nonetheless I'd suggest testing `tar` and see if it will meet your needs.  I just did a preliminary test on a modified folder that contains a customized image for the folder and it did archive the associated meta-data, at least some of it anyway.  That is to say I didn't test against `ditto` for comparison nor does that folder have ACL's, etc.

**Edit 2:** Considering the comment you made as to why you wanted to use `tar` and after tests between `ditto` and `tar` I'd say `tar` is probably going to meet your needs.  In either case I like redundancy and I do a Time Machine Backup as well as some other form of archival.  I do a separate image of my Home folder every once in a while to a compressed .dmg file.

Comment: Ditto will copy the files and folders fine, but the problem is, I'm not necessarily storing the backups on an HFS+ drive. In fact, I want to split them to 4GiB chunks so that I can transfer them on FAT32 in a pinch. Thus the need to tar them up.

Comment: @user280993, That is why I did a test and edited my answer.  See edited answer and then do some testing to confirm `tar` meets your needs.  Sorry I was going primarily by info in the man pages and they are not alway well written.

Comment: ah okay I see your edit. I'll test tar thoroughly. Thanks

Comment: @user280993 ditto can create CPIO archives compressed with gzip, bzip2, or PKZip. Yet another tool you could consider using is pax.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a command `hdiutil` which can be used to make a single dmg file from a directory, and the HFS flags are all preserved.